# Flutter request to server and show notification when app is closed

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications

I have a flutter mobile app and I want to request to server `every minute` and if any new data is available for user, show a `notification` ***WHEN THE APP IS CLOSED***.

can i do that without FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging) and APNS(Apple Push Notification Service)?

Comment: I know it may be a bit late to ask this question considering the post date, but are there specific reasons you're avoiding the usage of FCM?

Comment: Just one word "Sanction"

Answer (score 0):

its not good thing to request again again to server. instead of using api use web sockets and create a event. when ever there is new data for the user, even your app is terminated you will receive a notification using fcm .

please visit this page
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

Comment: In android work manager you can only do an event for every 15 minutes. And it's a very long time for app to get notifications